# Can I execute a stored procedure many time in a for loop?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, try-catch, sqlexception

I have a web service that executes a stored procedure. My web service function returns string[]. 
Sometimes I need to call the Web service many times.

For optimization reasons, I thought about adding a function to my web service which executes the stored procedure many times, in a **for loop**. That way the web service is called only once instead of several times.

1-Is my thinking correct ?

2-Below is my code, only the part specific to the problem described above.

3-Is it just not possible to do this using a for loop ?

**My Problem:** If I only use this code to call the stored procedure once, it works, but as soon as it is more (for loop iterates second time), the catch block is accessed.

If you can explain to me why is this happening and/or suggest a solution/workaround I would really appreciate.

```
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            //SqlTransaction transaction;
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
            cmd.Connection = connection;

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.CommandText = "InsertMsg";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = IDs[i];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = names[i];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = age;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            data[i] = IDs[i];
            transaction.Commit();
        }

        connection.Close();
        return data;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        data[0] = "Error";
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Have you debugged through the code to see what & why fails?

Comment: I am calling the web service through web reference, so I couldn't see how to debug it

Comment: Why not create a [table value parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead and pass all the data as a whole?

Comment: @SystemFailure If your service is running under IIS, attach to the worker process and put a breakpoint in this function to debug it.

Comment: You should put `connection` in a `using` statement. Right now you leave the connection open if a exception occurs.

Comment: Answer to your question(vague question) is, you're trying to open a connection which is already open. Don't do that.

Comment: @xxbbcc  I can't debug, because the Web service is hosted on IIS but not on the same machine where my winforms project is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues appears to be with the open and close statements. Close is outside the for loop, change it like

```
try
            {
            connection.Open();
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

          for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
             cmd = new SqlCommand();
            //SqlTransaction transaction;
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
            cmd.Connection = connection;

                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.CommandText = "InsertMsg";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = IDs[i];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = names[i];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = age;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                data[i] =  IDs[i];
                transaction.Commit();


                 }
          connection.Close();
                   return data;
        }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

                transaction.Rollback();
                data[0]="Error";
                return data;
            }
```

Closing the connection should be inside a finally block, better use a using statement instead. Also if possible do the looping and transaction inside the stored procedure which will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of the transaction inside the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Put your connection.Open() *outside* the loop

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to chime in and mention there's probably an advantage to using a DataAdapter in this circumstance:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2(v=vs.110).aspx

FTA - *"Batch support in ADO.NET allows a DataAdapter to group INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations from a DataSet or DataTable to the server, instead of sending one operation at a time. The reduction in the number of round trips to the server typically results in significant performance gains. "*

Answer (score 1):

I just winged this off real quick so ignore any syntax errors.  Basically you want to make sure you are taking advantage of "using" statements.  When you use a "using" it automatically calls Dispose() after the scope of the code has been reached, that way you dont have to worry about opening or closing a connection that is in use.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    //Initialize this however you need to
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = 
            new SqlCommand("InsertMsg", connection, connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            })
        {
            try
            {
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = IDs[i];
                command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = names[i];
                command.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = age;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                data[i] = IDs[i];
                command.Transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                command.Transaction.Rollback();
                data[0] = "Error";
            }
        }
    }
}
return data;
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. And I can't debug, because the Web service is hosted on IIS but not on the same machine where my winforms project is running

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand();

    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    cmd.CommandText = "InsertMsg";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter ID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    SqlParameter name = cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    SqlParameter age = cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.DateTime);

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        ID.Value = IDs[i];
        name.Value = names[i];
        age.Value = age;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        data[i] = IDs[i]; 
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    transaction.Rollback();
    data[0] = "Error";
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}

return data;
```